# TwinCAT 3 using FTP Functions

Tags: ftp, twincat

I am trying to use FTP functions on `CX8190` (Beckhoff). I want to use `FB_FTP_HostResolve`, then  `FB_FTP_Open` and after `FB_FTP_FileUploadEx` to upload a CSV file on FTP Server.

I used that way already on other `PLCs` of Beckhoff and also on this one before but now does not work anymore and I have no idea what can be the problem.

`FB_FTP_HostResolve` is the first function block that is triggered on this sequence and I get :

> Error ID 32769 - "Internal Error TwinCAT FTP Client."

Trial License for the system is there, CAB file of `TF6300` is saved and installed on device, FTP server is active. But error is there.

Is there anybody that knows what can be a problem? I already tried with installing new Image etc. I can not find the problem, neither does Beckhoff.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late but I faced the same issue today so if it can help someone :
You have to allow Fillezilla to communicate through windows firewall [FileZilla communicate through windows firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsIZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a workaround:
Call another windows ftp program from inside the plc with NT_StartProcess and by passing the correct command line arguments with the path to your .csv file.

[NT_StartProcess](https://infosys.beckhoff.de/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcplclibutilities/html/tcplclibutilities_nt_startprocess.htm&id=) on Beckhoff website.